# How to create a GRE Tunnel between public IP and private IP

Tags: networking, router, ip, tunnel

I have two Hosts. The one of them (Host A) is on a NAT. The other one (Host B) has Public IP. How to create a GRE tunnel between them? The only thing that I managed to work is a GRE Tunnel between router public IP and Host B, but this is not what I want. All three devices are running Debian OS.

A topology example:

```
|Host A              |     |Linux Router        |
|Private IP: 10.0.0.2|-----|Private IP: 10.0.0.1|              |Host B            |
                           |Public IP: 1.1.1.1  |--|Internet|--|Public IP: 2.2.2.2|
```

Answer (score 0):

GRE tunnel is simple but it use public ip address for source and destination.
There is no way to get around that for GRE TUNNEL and it doesn't have encryption.
You need to use something else combine with gre to get what you want.

PPPTP and other higher would do what you want